# Sequence of Infinitely Differentiable Functions Has Uniformly Converging Subsequence

Tags: analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of $C^\infty$ functions on a compact interval such that for each $k$ there exists $M_k$ such that $|f_n^{(k)}(x)|\leq M_k$ for all $n$ and $x.$ Prove that there exists a subsequence converging uniformly, together with the derivatives of all orders, to a $C^\infty$ function.

Could somebody provide a proof?

Answer (score 0):

We see that $|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)|=|f_{n}'(\xi_{n,x,y})||x-y|\leq M_{1}|x-y|$, so the sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous, by Arzela-Ascoli theorem there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_{k}}\}$ converges uniformly.

Use the same trick again we have $|f_{n_{k}}'(x)-f_{n_{k}}'(y)|\leq M_{2}|x-y|$, there is a further subsequence $\{f_{n_{k_{l}}}\}$ of $\{f_{n_{k}}\}$ such that $\{f_{n_{k_{l}}}'\}$ converges uniformly.

Now consider the diagonal sequence and you shall get what you want.

Comment: Doesn't uniform equicontinuity imply that $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\frac{1}{m}$ for all $m$ though? In our case don't we just have one instance?

Comment: I am a little confused of what you said. So given $\epsilon>0$, we choose $\delta=\epsilon/M_{1}$ so that when $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)|\leq M_{1}|x-y|<\epsilon$, so $\{f_{n}\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous.

Comment: Ahh I also checked another proof I did and I see now - could you explain the diagonalization argument more?

Comment: Write $\{f_{n}\}$ as $\{f_{(1,1)},f_{(2,1)},f_{(3,1)},...\}$ and its subsequence in argument as $\{f_{(1,2)},f_{(2,2)},f_{(3,2)},...\}$ and the so called further subsequence as $\{f_{(1,3)},f_{(2,3)},f_{(3,3)},...\}$. Now the so called diagonal sequence is then $\{f_{(1,1)},f_{(2,2)},f_{(3,3)},...\}$.

Comment: and how does this new sequence converge uniformly?

Comment: See my new edited post, just made a small mistake. Anyway, just now that the so called diagonal sequence is a subsequence for the selected subsequence of the (original) sequence $\{f_{n}\}$, I hope the wording right here does not make you confused.